# Why won't Wifi Shield detect any networks? Even really close

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, adafruit

I just purchased an Adafruit Wifi Shield CC3300 and strapped it onto my Arduino Uno board.

I'm running this basic sketch that I found to test the functionality of the Wifi Shield: http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoWiFiShield#toc1

Of course in my home I have Wifi, so I expected this sketch to show my Wifi name. However it doesn't. Instead I get this output on my serial monitor:

```
Init...
** Scan Networks **
Initializing Wifi...
MAC: 0:0:0:0:0:0
Scanning available networks...
** Scan Networks **
number of available networks:0
Scanning available networks...
** Scan Networks **
number of available networks:0
```

It just keeps going forever detecting zero networks.
I even took the Arduino and stood 3 feet away from my Wifi router. Still nothing.
I even tried making my cell phone a Wifi hotspot and holding it right next to the Arduino. Still nothing. And why does it say the MAC Address 0:0:0:0:0:0?

Can anyone suggest a fix?
FYI, here is a photo of what my setup looks like:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the Adafruit wifi board is compatible with the Arduino wifi shield libraries? Adafruit provides their own libraries on their tutorial page here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-cc3000-wifi?view=all#download-the-library I would try using their code with their hardware first.

Comment: Also what's up with the headers floating, are they even soldered to your WiFi shield?

Comment: Was this ever solved?  I'm having the same issue with an Arduino Uno and the Wifi/SD Shield.